# Why aren't signals simply called events?

Tags: python, signals, django-signals

From what I can tell, in Python and and Django, signals are simply delegated events.  Is there anything that functionally differentiates them from the typical notion of events in C#, Java, ActionScript, etc?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Actually, "signals" have been around longer than events have. In the earliest usage, a signal was an asynchronous way for processes to get notified that events had occurred. Since Unix is much older than Django (and since a lot of the Django work came from pydispatcher, where the original stuff was done), the name has stuck.

Events are really signals, you might say!

Answer (score 4):

Signals typically have an association with an operating system facility and events are typically application-defined.  In some technology stacks, the OS-level stuff may be hidden well enough that there isn't a difference in the API, but in others perhaps not.

Answer (score 2):

Afaik Qt had the first signal/slot implementation.  [Qt's docs](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/signalsandslots.html) explain the metaphor: "A signal is emitted when a particular event occurs".  The distinction is so subtle that the nomenclature has been blurred.

Answer (score 1):

You might as well ask "Why aren't events simply called signals?". Differences in terminology happen.

Comment: Moreover, I believe that "signals" has precedence.

Comment: It wasn't really a terminology question, I specifically asked if there was some sort of functional reason why the were named differently.

Comment: How is that not a terminology question? "Why don't these things that are the same have the same name?"

Comment: If you read the body of the question, and not the title, it is very clear, I'm asking whether there's a difference in functionality.